# Can I change my flight and travel dates before my B2 Visa interview?

Tags: usa, international-travel, b1-b2-visas, embassies, interview

I overstayed my US ESTA visa by about 90 days when I went over with my American now ex girlfriend (long story). I wasn't working while I was over there and she was funding my stay at the time.

Long story short, I came home and have been with my new girlfriend for over 3 years now and we have travel dates for a holiday all set in place (they were set when I applied for the visa, and are on my DS160 form) and my visa appointment is all scheduled, but the kicker is I need to change my flight and travel dates due to being currently out of work with a back injury, and not being able to fund it.

I'm supposed to be travelling in 6 weeks but I was hoping I could push it to 10 weeks maybe.

Any advice?

ADDITIONAL INFO: My current girlfriend has never been to the US so will be travelling on an ESTA, which she had applied for and attained already.

Comment: Are you sure you can get the visa?

Comment: If I were you I’d be cancelling the trip on medical grounds and claiming back the cost on my travel insurance. The USA, in common with many other countries, isn’t particularly well-known for being lenient to past overstayers, 90 days overstay cannot be explained away as an inadvertent oversight.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You can change the date of travel and bring the changed documents to interview and show to the officer to avoid deception. Travel dates changes for many reasons and it is generally a non-issue.

However, you have bigger problems to worry about. You had violated immigration laws, without a valid reason. You have to really convince the immigration officer that you are not a flight risk and never going to do that again. How are you planning to do that?

You are currently out of work. You don't have enough money to fund your trip. Your circumstances didn't improve. In the view of immigration officer, even without previous offence, you are likely to overstay. Probability of getting that visa is very low at this point, although you can definitely try.